# Authorization header sent from jquery to web API client is not properly received

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am doing a web api authorization

I making an authorization call from jquery to the web API with following code

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ulEmployees = $('#ulEmployee');
        var username = $('#uname').val();
        var password = $('#pword').val();
        username = "male";
        password = "male";
        $('#btn').click(function () {

            $.ajax({

                type: 'GET',
                url: 'api/Employees',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {

                    'Authorization': 'Basic' + btoa(username + ':' + password)

                },

                success: function (data)
                {
                    ulEmployees.empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, val) {

                        var fullName = val.FirstName + ''+val.gender + '' + val.LastName;
                        ulEmployees.append('<li>' + fullName + '</li>');

                    });
                },


            });
        });



        $('#btnclear').click(function(){

            ulEmployees.empty();

        });


        });

        });

</script>
```

but at controller side, I am not properly receiving the data

as bellow

actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter=null

actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Scheme="BasicbWFsZTptYWxl"

but accually i need as bellow

actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter="bWFsZTptYWxl"

actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Scheme="Basic"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need append one space symbol after 'Basic' in

```
'Authorization': 'Basic' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
```

So this string might be looks like

```
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
```